# dump all memory of perl script in certain point to an image

Tags: perl, memory, dump

Can I make some kind of dump file , which contains all the variables / objects / params that a script has , in a certain point of a script , so I can then start my script from this point again without the need to load them again and just load them from the file ?

I hope I was clear enough..

thanks !

Comment: Check [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.51/Storable.pm). It's not an automatic dump of the whole script, but you will be able to store the variables you want as long as they are within a reasonable memory footprint.

Comment: This was the intention of the builtin [`dump`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/dump.html) function, but it doesn't sound too easy to use.

Comment: In Storable I need to store each and every parameter , I want something that does memory freeze and dump all the script paramaters to a file,, if that possible of course